# Restarting machines in a docker swarm on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I have successfully created a docker swarm of 5 VMs on AWS using docker-machine. I stopped one VM using the command

`docker-machine stop aws01` and then I tried `docker-machine start aws01`

but Immediately I get an error

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: 
There was an error validating certificates for host "5x.20x.23x.10x:2376": 
x509: certificate is valid for 5x.2x.17x.25x, not 5x.20x.23x.10x
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers
```

Is really stoping and starting a container such a big deal that everytime I do this, I need to regenerate certs?

Is there a low impact way of stoping and starting my machines.

This never happened to me when I was using a local virtualbox VM for docker. This started only when I created docker machine on AWS.

As you can see that since I have 5 machines, starting and stopping is a big pain for me because I need to regenerate certs for all machines everytime I stop them? Obviously since its AWS I can't keep my machines running all the time.